# java.util.logger не создаёт файл и не сохраняет в него ничего

Tags: java, android, логирование, java-util-logger

Использую java.util.logger. Создаю и вызываю так:

```
LogManager man = LogManager.getLogManager();
try {
    manager.readConfiguration(getAssets().open("log.properties"));
    logger=Logger.getLogger("MyApp");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
logger.info("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
```

Его конфигурация:

```
# Глобальные настройки
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
# Конфигурация сохранения в файл
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/log.txt
```

Конфигурацию подтягивает нормально. Ошибок нет. Только файла лога по указанному пути не появляется. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: а что у вас `logger` ?

Comment: java.util.logging.Logger

Comment: Может приложение не находит файл с настройками или у него нет разрешения на запись в указанную вами директорию? Попробуйте использовать код на подобии как [тут](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/java-util-logging-example/) в 5 пункте

Comment: Похоже что логгер ничего не пишет, потому что к нему не прикреплен файл. Хотя возможно он читает не ту конфигурацию. Если это так, то поищи все файлы с конфигурациями и добавь туда настройки.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам. Если корректно всё сконфигурировать, особенно по части путей к файлу, работает.

```
log = Logger.getLogger("MyAppClass");
File f = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "log.txt");
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();                
}
FileHandler handler = new FileHandler(f.getAbsolutePath(), true);
log.addHandler(handler);
```