# java.util.logging работа с несколькими лог файлами одновременно

Tags: java, android, логирование

Как заставить стандартный логгер из java.util.logging писать в несколько лог файлов?

Чтобы в разных файлах писалась разная информация.

Работа в среде Java Android.

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы из 1 и таже информация писалась в 2 разных файла?

Comment: Разная информация в разных файлах.

Comment: Определяете 2 логгера, для каждого логгера используете свою проперти. В каждый логгер пишите свою информацию

Answer (score 3):

Берем вашу конфигурацию и правим

```
Logger logger1=Logger.getLogger("MyAppClass1");
Logger logger2=Logger.getLogger("MyAppClass2");

LogManager man1 = LogManager.getLogManager();
LogManager man2 = LogManager.getLogManager();

try {
    man1.readConfiguration(getAssets().open("log1.properties"));
    man2.readConfiguration(getAssets().open("log2.properties"));

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
logger1.info("A1");
logger2.info("A2");
```

## Глобальные настройки 1

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

## Конфигурация сохранения в файл

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/log1.txt
```

## Глобальные настройки 2

```
handlers = java.util.logging.FileHandler
```

## Конфигурация сохранения в файл

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/log2.txt
```

Comment: Как вы решили проблему с вашим предыдущим вопросом? У меня была подобная но с logj. Реализована примерно так. Но задаются не своими именами, а по имени класса.

Comment: К сожалению, в моём случае не помогло (честно пробовал). Но, всё равно спасибо. Может быть другим читателям вопроса поможет.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге разобрался сам. Нужно для каждого логгера указать немного отличающиеся имена и использовать код приведённый [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/976007/189348).